# Multivariate Berry-Esseen Theorem for possibly co-linear random vector

Tags: pr.probability, fourier-analysis

I was considering the following problem. Let $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. zero-mean random vectors with covariance matrix
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{Cov}\{(X_1,Y_1)\}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \sigma\\
    \sigma & 1
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
We assume the covariance matrix can be nearly degenerate, that is, $X$ and $Y$ can be highly Co-linear (but not exactly, since otherwise it reduces to univariate case). Now I want to know, if the multivariate Berry-Esseen Theorem still holds true. Mathematically speaking, does there exists a uniform constant $c>0$, such that 
\begin{equation}
  \sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2}\left|P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum X_i\leq x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum Y_i\leq y\right)-P\left(Z_1\leq x,Z_2\leq y\right)\right|\leq\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}},
\end{equation} 
where $(Z_1,Z_2)$ admits multivariate normal distribution with mean zero and covariance matrix $\mathrm{Cov}\{(X_1,Y_1)\}$, holds true for all $-1\leq\sigma\leq1$? I have found [some articles](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2244370) about multivariate Berry-Esseen theorem, usually they assume the covariance matrix to be identity matrix in order to bound the variance of each component, but I'm not sure whether Co-linearity affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Theorem 1.3 in the [article of Götze you linked to](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176990448), the answer is yes, because the result holds for all convex sets and by a linear transformation you can make the covariance an identity. In fact a result of Sazonov (1968) that Götze refers to already contains this.

Comment: Seems I finally got it, thank you very much!